# Need working example of i18n webpack plugin with angular2-webpack-plugin supporting multiple locales

Tags: angular, internationalization, webpack

I am using the following webpack config for prod env. Though it's working fine, its not the most optimised code as it runs every plugin for all locales. For example, ideally, copy plugin should be called only after the i18n plugin has run for all locales. or for example suppose i want to internationalize only main.bundle.js entry file and not others. Please help me write a more optimized config.

```
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); 
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const IgnorePlugin = require('webpack/lib/IgnorePlugin');
const DedupePlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');


const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}).metadata, {
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: false
});

const I18nPlugin  = require("webpack/node_modules/i18n-webpack-plugin");
var languages = {
  "en" : null,
  "hi": require("./locales/hi.json"),
  "de": require("./locales/de.json")
};

var path = require("path");
module.exports = function(env) {
 return Object.keys(languages).map(function(locale) {

  return  webpackMerge(commonConfig({env: ENV}), {


    debug: false,


    devtool: 'source-map',


    output: {


      path: helpers.root('dist'),
      //path: helpers.root('dist/' + METADATA.title + '/static'),


      filename: ((locale  == "en" )? "" : (locale +'.'))   + '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',


      sourceMapFilename: ((locale  == "en" )? "" : (locale +'.')) + '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map',


      chunkFilename: ((locale  == "en" )? "" : (locale +'.')) + '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js'

    },


    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.' + ((locale  == "en" )? "" : (locale +'.'))  +'html',
        chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
      }),
       new I18nPlugin(
                languages[locale]
            ),

      new WebpackMd5Hash(),



      new DefinePlugin({
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        'process.env': {
          'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
          'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
        }
      }),
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        beautify: false, //prod
        mangle: { screw_ie8 : true, keep_fnames: true }, //prod
        compress: { screw_ie8: true }, //prod
        comments: false //prod
      }),


      new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /angular2-hmr/,
        helpers.root('config/modules/angular2-hmr-prod.js')
      ),



    ],


    tslint: {
      emitErrors: true,
      failOnHint: true,
      resourcePath: 'src'
    },

    *ngFor
    htmlLoader: {
      minimize: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: false,
      caseSensitive: true,
      customAttrSurround: [
        [/#/, /(?:)/],
        [/\*/, /(?:)/],
        [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/]
      ],
      customAttrAssign: [/\)?\]?=/]
    },

    /*
     * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
     * Description: Node configuration
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
     */
    node: {
      global: 'window',
      crypto: 'empty',
      process: false,
      module: false,
      clearImmediate: false,
      setImmediate: false
    }

  });


});


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was implementing localization for my angular 2 project I ended up making a service.  Pass in the locale and key then return the localized string.  I'm not sure what advantage adding localization as a web pack plugin would provide.

Comment: Yes..even I considered that..there are inherent advantage of using run time localisation through service as you rightly pointed out...but for me the problem is, amount of localisation strings are pretty high and the application is supposed to run on low end android phones which has limited memory and processing power..loading pre translated locale files helps me out there..

Answer (score 0):

Seems [intl-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/oklas/intl-webpack-plugin) much simple to use:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(intl|i18n|yml|yaml)$/i,
        use: [
          IntlPlugin.loader()
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new IntlPlugin({
      search: [ './locales/**/*.json' ]
    })
```